# Django: Sort a queryset by counting the many to many objects

Tags: django, count, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have searched everywhere but I cannot find the solution for this problem, which in a first look should be trivial.

Please consider the Djano Model:

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institution=models.CharField(max_length=128)


class TeamModel(models.Model):
    creator= models.ForeignKey(UserModel,related_name='creator')
    members= models.ManyToManyField(UserModel,related_name='teams'))
    name=models.CharField(max_length=64)`
```

Those models are fixed, I cannot change them. I can of course include new fields.

To retrieve the teams associated with a user, I can simply do:

```
queryset= instance_UserModel.teams.all()
```

It works perfectly! Now I want to order the teams by the number of members.

```
queryset= queryset.annotate(num_members=Count('members')).order_by('num_members')
```

It does not work, because num_members value is always "1"!

```
print queryset[0].num_members
print queryset[1].num_members
```

returns always "1". What is happening???!!!

Thank you in advance,

CBar

Comment: Just to clarify, `queryset` on your line with `annotate` is equivalent to `instance_UserModel.teams.all()` or `TeamModel.objects.all()`?

Comment: Please copy-paste your code as-is, there are at least 2 typos in your code here that would raise syntax errors.

Comment: Dear Lorenzo, the way I understood in the Django documentation, queryset is a collection of objects equivalent to TeamModel.objects.all().

Comment: queryset is equivalent to instance_UserModel.teammodel_set.all(). And instance_UserModel=UserModel.objects.get(user=request.user).

Comment: Sorry for the typos C14. I slightly modified the variable names from original code to make it clearer. Next time I will do as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This was not tested

```
class TeamModel(models.Model):
    creator= models.ForeignKey(UserModel,related_name='creator')
    members= models.ManyToManyField(UserModel,related_name='teams'))
    name=models.CharField(max_length=64)`
```

views.py

```
import operator

teams = TeamModel.objects.all()
team_member_count = {}
for team in teams:
   team_member_count[team.name] = team.members.all.count()

sorted_teams_by_member_count = sorted(team_member_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Dear rwx, I dont see how this will selected the teams for a specific user. Pls correct me if I am wrong, but I understood that your code only creates an sorted list of tuples with the of the teams and count. For this I would rather write TeamModel.objects.all().annotate(num_members=Count('members')).order_by('num_members'). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't know how efficient it is regarding database operations. And I still do not understand why my previous code does not work.

```
    qUserTeams=instance_UserModel.teams.all()
    qAllTeams=TeamModel.objects.all().annotate(num_members=Count('members')).order_by('num_members')
    queryset= qAllTeams & qUserTeams
```